# Images not showing on Xcode 6 using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I try to run the program compiles and I don't receive any errors. Everything works as it should except that the image is not showing on the View Controller. Can't figure where why the image is not showing. I appreciate any inputs. Here is my code:

ViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowItemDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ItemDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.itemDesc = [listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.itemName = [listTimes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.pictureImageView = [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

ItemDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ItemDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *itemTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemDesc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView* pictureImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *picImageView;


@end
```

ItemViewController.m

```
#import "ItemDetailViewController.h"

@interface ItemDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation ItemDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.itemLabel.text = self.itemName;
    self.itemTitle.text = self.itemDesc;
    self.pictureImageView.image = self.picImageView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Just try after changing line destViewController.pictureImageView = [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; with destViewController. picImageView = [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: You are setting the pictureImageView image in viewDidLoad may be the value of self.picImageView is nil.

Comment: I tried that and got this:

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: what is the value of [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is UIImage or something else?

Comment: Try to set this line     self.pictureImageView.image = self.picImageView; in ViewDidAppear

Comment: The image is still not showing...

Comment: Please Have you got the image or not? like Adding condition. if(!self.picImageView){NSLog(@"No image");}else{self.pictureImageView.image = self.picImageView;}

Comment: iF you get No image then you are not getting UIImage value properly

Answer (score 0):

At the time of `viewDidLoad`, chances are that `self.picImageView` is empty. Please check that.

Then, in order to set the picture, write a function like:

```
-(void) setPicImageView: (UIImage*) picImage{
    self.picImageView = picImage;
    self.pictureImageView.image = picImage;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You've got the diagnosis right but the wrong solution.  As you point out there's no point in setting the image view image during the prepareForSegue.  Just set the image and apply it to the imageView on viewWillAppear.

Comment: I got an error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0xfff57654ff8

Comment: @danh trying to put the addition of the image on ViewWillAppear almost certainly will create issues, since the device will try to set the image every time the view controller appears on screen (whether or not it was previously release). From experience, I've noticed that it's always better to create user-called functions for setting properties, than to use view lifecycle functions. Just saying.

Comment: Thank you for all the inputs however it's just the third day of our lecture and I am still trying to understand everything

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your prepare for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowItemDetail"]) {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       ItemDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.itemDesc = [listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       destViewController.itemName = [listTimes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       destViewController.picImageView = [listImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

And in your viewDidLoad try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   self.itemLabel.text = self.itemName;
   self.itemTitle.text = self.itemDesc;
   self.pictureImageView.image = self.picImageView;
}
```